# Field Validation in Element.xml (Schema.xml) SharePoint 2013 List

Tags: elements-xml, validation-list-items

I have custom list in SharePoint 2013. That custom list made in element.xml and schema.xml. I am trying to put validation on list field using below method.
For ex : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/validation-element-list
But it doesn't reflect anything on SharePoint side.

Is anyone done this before? If yes then can you please suggest me the best way?
And I am even not sure how to put that script in validation element.xml

Thanks,
Heena.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I tested with elements.xml.

The formula goes into the  tag.

This is a validation rule that check if the field contains "http:// or "https://".

```
    <Field
        Type="Text"
        DisplayName="LocationUrl"
        Required="FALSE"
        EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"
        Indexed="FALSE"
        MaxLength="255"
        ID="{5a6b348e-cc0d-4a50-9a7d-5a680c36e0b6}"
        SourceID="{c66bbf65-c9ff-40ee-9c0e-6895e5a72cfe}" StaticName="LocationUrl"
        Name="LocationUrl" ColName="nvarchar10" RowOrdinal="0"
        CustomFormatter="" Version="
        5">
    <Validation Message="Valid URL must include http:// or https:// or empty">=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(&quot;http://&quot;,LocationUrl)),ISNUMBER(FIND(&quot;https://&quot;,LocationUrl)),LocationUrl=&quot;&quot;)</Validation>
    </Field>
```